# Mysql Compare three datetime fields

Tags: mysql, datetime

I  want to get `latest_date` from a database that is between 3 dates field.
Now I am using the following query but it is not ok for my requirement.
How to compare 3 date field to get `latest_date` ?

```
SELECT DISTINCT e.id, MAX( cc.updated ) AS clinicComment_date, MAX( af.created ) AS attenderInfo_created, e.updated AS event_updated,
(
 CASE 
 WHEN MAX( cc.updated ) > MAX( af.created ) 
 THEN MAX( cc.updated ) 
 WHEN MAX( cc.updated ) < MAX( af.created ) 
 THEN MAX( af.created ) 
 ELSE e.updated
 END
) AS latest_date
FROM Event e
LEFT JOIN EventClinic ec ON e.id = ec.event_id
LEFT JOIN ClinicComment cc ON ec.clinic_id = cc.clinic_id
LEFT JOIN AttendersInfo af ON af.event_id = e.id
WHERE e.status =  'active'
AND (
e.id =43
OR e.id =45
)
GROUP BY e.title
ORDER BY latest_date DESC
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`GREATEST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) function

```
GREATEST(cc.updated, af.created, e.updated) AS latest_date
```

THis one should give you the latest date for a single row

If you want the latest between all the rows:

```
MAX(GREATEST(cc.updated, af.created, e.updated)) AS latest_date
```

that's the same of doing

```
GREATEST(MAX(cc.updated), MAX(af.created), MAX(e.updated)) AS latest_date
```

To deal with NULL values you can use `COALESCE`

```
GREATEST(
    COALESCE(MAX(cc.updated), 0), 
    COALESCE(MAX(af.created), 0),  
    COALESCE(MAX(e.updated), 0) 
) AS latest_date
```

Or

```
 MAX(
    GREATEST(
        COALESCE(cc.updated), 0), 
        COALESCE(af.created), 0),  
        COALESCE(e.updated), 0) 
)) AS latest_date
```

the result should be the same, maybe they differ in performance, I don't know

Comment: I run with this query 
    GREATEST(MAX(cc.updated), MAX(af.created), MAX(e.updated)) AS      latest_date

but there is a preoblem .
When one datefield is null , the latest_date would be null.

Comment: How can I do for some datefield with `NULL` value ?

Comment: so you have to check for every column against ISNULL and replace NULL values with another value, I'll edit my answer

Comment: Thank you so much.
That is work .
You saved my time.
BTW, you should change `COLAESCE` to `COALESCE`

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a funciton called `GREATEST()`. You can replace the lines

```
(
 CASE 
 WHEN MAX( cc.updated ) > MAX( af.created ) 
 THEN MAX( cc.updated ) 
 WHEN MAX( cc.updated ) < MAX( af.created ) 
 THEN MAX( af.created ) 
 ELSE e.updated
 END
) AS latest_date
```

with `GREATEST(MAX(cc.updated), MAX(af.created)) AS latest_date` and add a third field to that.

Comment: yes, I try with this query GREATEST(MAX(cc.updated), MAX(af.created), MAX(e.updated)) AS latest_date  but there is a preoblem . When one datefield is `NULL` , the latest_date would be `NULL`. How can I do for some datefield with `NULL` value ? .

Answer (score 0):

I can see the problem in your Case statement where every condition is not met. Mysql provides GREATEST function to return greatest value

Try this

```
select DISTINCT e.id,GREATEST(MAX( cc.updated ),MAX( af.created ),e.updated) as Latest_Date
FROM Event e
LEFT JOIN EventClinic ec ON e.id = ec.event_id
LEFT JOIN ClinicComment cc ON ec.clinic_id = cc.clinic_id
LEFT JOIN AttendersInfo af ON af.event_id = e.id
WHERE e.status =  'active'
AND ( e.id =43 OR e.id =45 )
GROUP BY e.title
ORDER BY latest_date DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
greatest(isnull(column1,0),isnull(column2,0),isnull(column3,0))
```

The above query will check each column if that is null. If the value is null that will take the value 0. Then it will give you greatest value

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information.